# Getting firefox to stop crashing[parrotsec rpi3b+]

Tags: pi-3

I have the rpi3b+ and i can get it to boot to desktop but getting firefox to load an not crash is a chore having firefox uo an running woluld make running the system easier so i could trouble shoot the issues without having to boot into another os on berryboot.

Comment: what is `parrotsec` in the title? why firefox? chromium works really well on a pi, compared to firefox

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) Please write proper sentences so that people does not have to puzzle what you mean. They are then more motivated to help you for free. And please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: its what comes installed on parrot os